# jQuery Passing Carriage Return

Tags: jquery, html

I've been working on this project but so far, couldn't figure out how to proceed: I have a *textarea* where the user should put the input and that input should print directly into a *span* 
By now I could actually make this happen, but when the user input some carriage return (enter), the *span* text shows only a space (not actually a Carriage Return).

I've made a (compact) fiddle to show how it's like at this moment. Hope someone can help me.

https://jsfiddle.net/fqnngd44/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#input').keyup(function() {
      $('#text').text($(this).val());
   });
});
```

(In other words: I need the *textarea* to print an actually carriage return (instead of just a space) when the enter key is pressed.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is because HTML converts any group of whitespace characters (space, tab, carriage return, etc.) to a single space.

To get around this you can replace any new line in your `textarea` with a `<br />`. Also note that you'll need to use `html()` instead of `text()` to display the value, otherwise it will be HTML encoded. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#input').keyup(e => {
    $('#text').html($(e.target).val().replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />'));
  });
});
```

```css
#text {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Type in to the box, including carriage returns:<br />
<textarea id="input" name="input" type="textarea" maxlength="99"></textarea>
<span id="text"></span>
```

Comment: This solution doesn't print spaces if a line starts with spaces. Probably the most simple solution is to do this with CSS, which prints both new lines and spaces. (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

In the [jQuery documentation for .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/), it has the following warning (and suggestion)

> **Note**: At present, using .val() on textarea elements strips carriage return characters from the browser-reported value. When this value is sent to the server via XHR however, carriage returns are preserved (or added by browsers which do not include them in the raw value). A workaround for this issue can be achieved using a valHook as follows:

```
$.valHooks.textarea = {
  get: function( elem ) {
    return elem.value.replace( /\r?\n/g, "\r\n" );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In html any sequence of white space is collapsed to a single space, carriage returns are classified as white space so that happens. For that not to happen you can use a `<pre>` tag or use the style `white-space:pre`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#input').keyup(function() {
        $('#text').text($(this).val());
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input" name="input" type="textarea" maxlength="99"></textarea>
<pre id="text"></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably the most easy way to do that is to format the text with `white-space: pre;`.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/fqnngd44/10/